# A technical question regarding the site code

Tags: support, source-code

When I view source of this page, there's a StackExchange object being used. However, I can't find where it's declared - I've checked all sources in Chrome's Developer tools.

Secondly, the hyperlink we use to accept an answer - where is the code that gets executed when we click it? There's no onClick attribute there.

Also, I can see there are some 'data-verb-accept' and 'data-title-accept' attributes used inside the hyperlink. Where are their definitions?

Below is the code of "accept the answer" hyperlink.

```
<a id="vote-accepted-1091651" 
class="vote-accepted-off vote-accepted-on" 
href="javascript:void(0);"
data-title-accept="Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (click again to undo)" 
data-verb-accept="accept"
data-title-unaccept="Click to undo acceptance of this answer; you accepted this answer yesterday" 
data-verb-unaccept="unaccept"></a>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "definitions" for the data- attributes?

Comment: @ProgramFOX I assume he means where's the code that interacts with those attributes to add functionality to the element.

Comment: Maybe he's looking for the DTD - in which case he'll never find one.

Comment: Are you trying to hack the checkmark? :)

Comment: Perhaps he wants to spend several hours of coding and researching to save one click per question on auto-upvote. Then realise it breaks on sites where he doesn't have 15 rep anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a SE developer, but inspecting the page source and associated JS files revealed some information.

1. The `StackExchange` object and nested objects are defined in `/content/Js/stub.en.js`.
2. There is no `onClick` attribute because the click handler gets set from JavaScript code - then there's no onClick attribute necessary.
3. About the `data-` attributes, I'm not sure what you mean by "definition", but these attributes are not really 'defined' somewhere. It justs uses the [HTML5 data-* attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). Its *content* is set from the backend codebase written in C#, said Oded in his comment.

Comment: You forgot the key word: jQuery. :)

Comment: The data for the data attributes is defined in our back end codebase, in C# (and in the translation database for localized sites).

Comment: 1. Well, I can't see var StackExchange anywhere in this file.
2. Supposedly the event is handled by method passed to addEventListener method. I can't find it in any source file though.

Comment: @user4205580 1. I see a `window.StackExchange={}` in the stub.en.js file. 2. Stack Exchange uses jQuery, so it's set by `.click(...)` or `.on("click", ...)`. I cannot find the actual location, but as there's no onClick attribute, I'm sure that way is used.

Comment: 1. Do you know what {} do in this case?
2. You can't find it, but it has to be in the sources, right?

Comment: @user4205580 1. The `{}` sets an empty object to `StackExchange`. This object will receive other objects, but those come from different locations in the source. 2. Yes, it has to be there. The SE JavaScript is compressed, so it's not very easy to read and find things like this.